# My custom list of "things" doesn't show the content inside the list

Tags: tocloft

I am writing a document which contains a series of math formulas. I'm using the package [tocloft](https://ctan.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/tocloft/tocloft.pdf), which has a section that explains how to make a ***new list of*** something. I did exactly what it is written in the documentation but every time the document is compiled and viewed the list of math formulas doesn't appear. The only thing that shows up from the command I defined `\listofformulation` is the title of the name of the list, but it's smaller than the titles of table of contents, list of figures and list of tables.

Another thing I noticed from the documentation of tocloft is everytime a new formula is written in the document and it's compiled it should be added in a file called *jobname.ext* where:

- **jobname**: Is the name of the documentation file.
- **ext**: Is the extention of the file.

But this file it doesn't show up in the directory where I'm writing my documentation.

Here is what I have wrote in the *.tex* file:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,oneside,italian]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[bottom]{footmisc}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[bibstyle=numeric,backend=biber,sorting=nty]{biblatex}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage[acronym,toc,nomain]{glossaries}

\addbibresource{Bibliografia/bibliografia.bib} 

\definecolor{darkblue}{rgb}{0.0,0.0,0.6}
\definecolor{darkgreen}{rgb}{0.0,0.6,0.0}

\newcommand{\listofformulation}{Elenco delle formule}

\newlistof{formula}{for}{\listofformulation}

\newcommand{\formula}[1]
{%
    \refstepcounter{formula}
    \par\noindent{\textbf{Formula \theformula}: #1}
    \phantomsection
    \addcontentsline{for}{formula}{\protect\numberline{\theformula}#1}\par
}

\begin{document}
    
    \pagenumbering{gobble}

    %Title of the document
    
    \newpage
    
    \pagenumbering{roman}
    
    \tableofcontents
    
    \newpage
    \listoffigures
    
    \newpage
    \listoftables
    
    \newpage
    
    \listofformulation
    
    \newpage
    
    \pagenumbering{arabic}

    \input{document1.tex}
    
    \newpage

    \formula{Testing}   
    \label{for:Testing}
    
\end{document}
```

I'm using TexStudio (version 2.12.16) for writing the document. I have installed this from [Flathub](https://flathub.org/apps/details/org.texstudio.TeXstudio).

What I want is simply the list of math formulas showing up correctly, with the page reference, from the `\listofformulation` command.

## EDIT

After I have changed the name of the command `\listofformulation` to `\listofformula`, suggested by [Cicada](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/182648/cicada), another thing I have changed is the command to show the list of formulas from `\listofformulation` into `\listof{formula}{Elenco delle formule}` and I finally got the list of formulas as I wanted.

Here are the commands I changed in the preamble

```
\newcommand{\listofformula}{Elenco delle formule}

\newlistof{formula}{for}{\listofformula}
```

And this is the one inside the document:

```
%\listofformula
\listof{formula}{Elenco delle formule}
```

Comment: Welcome to tex.se. Use `\listofformula` instead of `\listofformulation`. Manual p 13: "`\newlistof[chapter]{answer}{ans}{\listanswername}`
will create a new `answer` counter that will be reset at the start of each
`\chapter{...}`. Any answer titles will be written to the file `jobname.ans` and `\listanswername` will be used as the list heading. A command `\listofanswer` is created which can be used just like the `\listoftables`..."

Comment: @Cicada Would you like to provide an answer based on your comment? If not, I might do so!!!!!

Comment: @PeterWilson  By all means! :)

Comment: Hi @Cicada. I did exactly what you wrote by changing `\listofformulation` in `\listofformula` but when I compile the document I get the following error: `TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [grouping levels=255]. \listofformula` which I don't understand what does it mean. To solve the problem I simply changed the command inside the **document** `\listofformula` to `\listof{formula}{Elenco delle formule}` and I have the entire list of math formulations.

Comment: @Simone I tested without `bibliografia.bib` and `\input{document1.tex}` (because I don't have those files). If the capacity problem is still outstanding, ask a separate question.

Comment: @Cicada Thank for your reply. Anyway, as I have already written in the previous comment, I was able to solve my problem by simply changing the command `\listofformula` with `\listof{formula}{Elenco delle formule}` and my list of math formulas appears as I wanted since the beginning. So the problem is solved in my opinion.

Comment: Conincidence. :) The `float` package (2001) defines a `\newfloat` command and "also a `\listof` command that prints a listing of all the floats of a given type..." which takes two parameters. The command `\listof{formula}{Elenco delle formule}` produces no list for me, presumably because no `\newfloat` is defined in the MWE. The `tocloft` package (2020) provides the `\newlistof` command as used in the MWE and in the question. You may comment out `\usepackage{tocloft}` (and its related commands), therefore, and your list should remain.

Comment: @Cicada Understood. Thank you for the reply.